# var undefined = true;

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some experimenting with this malicious JavaScript line: `var undefined = true;`

Every uninitialized variable in JavaScript has the value of `undefined` which is just a variable that holds the special value of `'undefined'`, so the following should execute the `alert`:

```
var undefined = true, 
    x;

if (x) {
    alert('ok');
}
```

But it doesn't, and my question is why?

On further experimentation, I tried the following:

```
var undefined = true, 
    x = undefined;

if (x) {
    alert('ok');
}
```

This time, the `alert` is executed.

So my question is...since in the first snippet `x` holds `undefined` (because it is not initialized), why didn't the `alert` execute?  The strange thing is that when explicitly stating that `x` is `undefined` (`x = undefined`), the `alert` executed...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a difference between a variable named `undefined` and the value called `undefined`.

```
var undefined = true, 
    x;
```

In this example, the variable `undefined` is set to the value `true`, and `x` to the value (not the variable!) `undefined`.

```
var undefined = true, 
    x = undefined;
```

In this example, the variable `undefined` is set to the value `true` as well, and `x` is set to the value contained in the variable `undefined` (which is `true`).

So, while you can declare a variable named `undefined`, you cannot change the fact that non-initialized variables are set to the value `undefined`.

Comment: Hehe; what would happen if the variable `undefined` was the value `undefined`?

Comment: @Pindatjuh: the same as if the variable had any other name. There is nothing special about a variable named `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Just declaring a variable called "undefined" does not mean that you're overriding the built-in concept of what the native "undefined" value is.

Imagine if Java would let you use "null" as an identifier.  Well, I guess Java doesn't have the same coercion as Javascript.  Anyway the Javascript statement

```
if (x) alert("foo");
```

involves an implicit coercion of the value of "x" to boolean. The value isn't defined, so its coercion to "boolean" results in `false`.

Comment: @Andreas Grech - Bizarrely, `"\n\t" == true` is also actually `false`.

Comment: Actually, the concept of true in JavaScript is every value except null, undefined, the empty string '', `NaN`, `0` and `false`

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized variables get the special value `undefined`. When you assign a variable to another variable you're giving it a string that references a variable you've defined within the current scope. In this case you've defined a variable named `undefined` so the JavaScript engine will look first through the variables, see that you've named one `undefined` and then assign it that variable.