# undefined as a valid variable name in local scope

Tags: javascript, undefined

I've given some thoughts on declaring a variable called `undefined` and evaluating a truthy if-else expression with it. I found out that it is not possible in global scope. But in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) I've found some interesting insight about the `undefined` datatype. I am directly quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

> undefined is a property of the global object; i.e., it is a variable
>   in global scope.

It doesn't say anything about local scope. That means i can create one in local scope. So, I move on to put this insight to test. I have created an object and assign a method to it

```
var person = {
   method : function(){

       var undefined = 2

       if(undefined){
          console.log("undefined works as a variable")
       }

   }
}

person.method()
```

And guess what! the if statement passes the test and the string inside the `console.log()` gets printed on the console.This might be a dangerous thing and of course a bad practice. Is there any way to prevent the declaration of a variable named after `undefined` keyword in javascript's local scope ? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var undefined = true;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534260/var-undefined-true)

Comment: @nem035 will not work

Comment: *"Is there any way to prevent the declaration of a variable named after `undefined` keyword in javascript's local scope ?"* Why exactly are you asking? What's your ultimate goal? Do you want to prevent yourself from creating such a variable? Who else is writing code "in local scope" if not yourself?

Comment: @FelixKling i would like to know if i can throw any exception if something like this ever happen. Any beginner can make this kind of mistake. I tried with "use strict" but that didn't work.

Comment: You could create an eslint rule for that. But in general I doubt that somebody would "accidentally" overwrite `undefined` and break their own code.

Comment: To expand on this a little more: There are many things one can do to accidentally "break" their code and code linting is currently the most common way to guard against that. Another example would be putting the a line break after `return`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work around accidental modification of `undefined`, you should not write this dangerous word in your code at all.

Since you only need read access to `undefined`, it is recommended to *always* use `void 0` instead, which returns `undefined`.

```js
var person = {
   method: function() {

       var undefined = 2

       if(void 0) {
          console.log("this should never be printed")
       } else {
          console.log("void 0 is always undefined, no matter what you do")
       }

   }
}

person.method()
```

How to work with `void 0` and completely get rid of the word "undefined"?

```
// Turn
if(myVariable === undefined) { ... }
if(typeof myVariable === "undefined") { ... }
// into
if(myVariable === void 0) { ... }

// Turn
if((myVariable === undefined) || (myVariable === null)) { ... }
// into
if(myVariable == null) { ... }

// Turn
myObject.someKey = undefined
// into
myObject.someKey = void 0
```

Comment: But, `if(void 0) {` is really not useful as no one ever actually write `if(undefined) {`. What's more likely is that something will need to be tested against `undefined`, like: `if(x === undefined) {`. How would that work with `void 0`?

Comment: `if(x === void 0) {` (see my answer)

Comment: Why not just `if(x){}`?

Comment: It seems much simpler to me to wrap my code in `(function(undefined) { ... }())` instead. Using `void 0` makes the code more difficult to understand.

Comment: Because it has a different meaning.

Comment: `if(x)` will test for a non-undefined, non-null, non-falsey value, which is really what were interested in here.

Comment: Nobody forces you to use `void 0`. But since it is the recommended workaround, most people will do it that way.

Comment: @FelixKling Agreed. That's what I reference in my answer.

Comment: `if(x)` is not problematic (if you understand what it does). But since we are discussing the behavior of `undefined` (and not the behavior of `if(x)`), I listed problems you can run into when using it.

Comment: To me, the use of void(0) seems like far more simpler than declaring  a wrapper function with an argument undefined every time  :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of JavaScript!

There is no way to prevent someone from doing this, but there is a way to ensure that `undefined` will mean `undefined` if you set up your functions as follows (not that you should really have to do this because it would be very bad practice for anyone to actually set up a variable named `undefined`). Essentially smaller scoped functions could hide a higher scoped `undefined` variable.

```js
// This is just a way to get a variable called "undefined"
function wrapper(){
  var undefined = 10;
  console.log("wrapper says undefined is: " + undefined);

  // This function declared a parameter called "undefined",
  // but if the function gets called with no argument, then
  // the value of this, more local, argument will truly be
  // undefined. If arguments are needed, just add "undefined" 
  // to the end of the list.
  function foo(undefined){
    // Formal test to ensure that undefined is what we believe it to be:
    if(typeof undefined === "undefined"){
      console.log("foo says undefined is: " + undefined);
    }
  }
  
  // When foo is called with no arguments passed in, the parameter
  // "undefined" will take on a value of undefined within the scope
  // of that function.
  foo();
}

wrapper();
```

Now, that's a bit contrived as you're not going to set up all your functions with a "fake" argument, but you could test to see if `undefined` has been altered with:

```js
function wrapper(){
  var undefined = 10;
  console.log(undefined);
  
  function foo(){
  
    if(typeof undefined === "undefined"){
       // undefined has not been altered
    } else {
       // undefined has been altered, so reset it for this scope:
       let undefined;
       console.log(undefined);
    }
 
  }
  
  foo();
}

wrapper();
```

In the end though, you could simply prevent this from affecting your functions by adding `var undefined` in your functions. Hoisting will make sure that this kicks in at the top of your function, no matter where you declare it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any way to stop it, but yes, You can restrict it passing the yes inside If you can make the scope local using ES6.

You will find how scope if changed now and it's not the same thing.

```
var person = {
   method : function(){

   let undefined = 2

   if(undefined){
      console.log("undefined works as a variable")
   }

   }
}
```